# Cant send form with html content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

Hello I have a really annoying problem with my rails 3.0 form. I'm using CKEditor to let the user edit html content of their page. Everything was working fine in rails 2  he made a lot of pages with html content. But then I needed to update the rails gem to 3.0.1 since the was a need for that (server admins updated to rails 3 and removed 2).

After this change He wanted to edit the pages for a new season (tourism oriented business). Some of the pages could't be updated I get a

```
403 Forbidden

Access to this resource on the server is denied!`
```

It drives me nuts, I tried every solution that could be relevant but still no luck.

I figure it could has to do with the html content submitted with form because when I delete the content and put some simple paragraph text it works OK. But I have no idea what could it be.

Here's a sample form

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pages/113" class="jNice" id="edit_page_113" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="w5ZUDHYHnFKHhLQc6UO/a3zwbN5p6JMgKYUWlVhbMiU=" /></div>
<fieldset>
<p>
<label for="page_category_id">Kategoria:</label>
<select id="page_category_id" name="page[category_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="13">School And Study Tours Groups</option>
<option value="23" selected="selected">Regular &amp; Group Tours To Poland </option>
<option value="14">Jewish History And Heritage Tours</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="page_name">Nazwa podstrony:</label>
<input id="page_name" name="page[name]" size="30" type="text" value="Poland in a week - the Southern face" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="page_cities">Miasta imprezy:</label>
<input id="page_cities" name="page[cities]" size="30" type="text" value="Warsaw - Krakow - Wieliczka - Auschwitz - Czestochowa" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="page_keywords">Słowa kluczowe:</label>
<input id="page_keywords" name="page[keywords]" size="30" type="text" value="Poland tour,  tour of Warsaw, tours of Cracow, czestochowa Jasna gora tour" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="page_description">Skrócony opis:</label>
<input id="page_description" name="page[description]" size="30" type="text" value="2012 tour to Poland with visit to Wieliczka Salt Mine and Czestochowa " />
</p>
<p>
<label for="page_tour_of_the_month">Tour of the month na stronie głównej?:</label>
<input name="page[tour_of_the_month]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="page_tour_of_the_month" name="page[tour_of_the_month]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="page_html_body">Zawartość:</label>
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="40" id="page_html_body" name="page[html_body]" rows="20">test</textarea>
</p>
<p>
<label for="page_published">Opublikowana?:</label>
<input name="page[published]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input checked="checked" id="page_published" name="page[published]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="page_show_request_link">Pokaż link rezerwacyjny?:</label>
<input name="page[show_request_link]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input checked="checked" id="page_show_request_link" name="page[show_request_link]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</p>
</fieldset>

<p><input id="page_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="edytuj" /></p>
</form>
```

Here's the content of the routes.rb file

```
Gfp3::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :newscasts do
    get :publish, :on => :member
  end

  resources :links
  resources :payments
  resources :fronts
  resources :categories do
    collection do
       :sort
    end
  end

  resources :pages do
    get :publish, :on => :member
  end
  resources :menus

  match 'login',:to=>'index#login'
  match 'logout', :to=>'index#logout'
  match 'images', :to=>'images#index'
  match 'images/upload', :to=>'images#upload'
  match 'front_page',:to=>'front_page#index'
  match 'search',:to=>'index#search'

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  root :to => 'index#index'
    match ':id',:to=>"pages#show"
end
```

Theese are the gems used in the app

```
gem 'mongrel'
gem 'rails', '3.0.1'
gem 'haml'

gem "will_paginate", "3.0.pre2"
gem 'mysql',"2.8.1"
```

Comment: Please post the log when you try to post this form. It probably has nothing to do with the values inside your form. Do you have any authentication plugins installed?

Comment: The log says nothing when I send the form (i used a blank log file for this). I don't use any auth plugins just simple cookie file and before method to authenticate the admin parts.

Answer (score 0):

Look like routes wrong defined or not defined

Comment: The routes seem to be OK the part which defines pages is   
resources :pages do
    get :publish, :on => :member
  end

Comment: POST method execute create action. Create action can't have ID so you need to use PUT method

Comment: but there's a input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" in the form

Comment: Try remove match line. Code 403 means refuse connection. This has nothing to do with the content subject

Comment: Can you port log from development.log as wrote iain? Not all, just that part describing PUT operation. Give also Gemfile or gem list you use. From ware you have taht part: `match ':id',:to=>"pages#show"`. I first see it. Maybe this is root of all evil?

Comment: The log is empty when I submit the form. I've placed the gems list above. Also I found that the error could me related to mod_security but I don't know if this should affect a rails app

Comment: Maybe in your server logs is more usefull information. Check nginx||apache logfile. Don't write which u use. If mod_security problem the answer is there.

Comment: I'm contacting the server admins, i'll post the results here.

Comment: The issue was something with the server setting I aske if the admins would share the information on what exactly it was. If they do I'll post it here

Comment: OK. We may talk on may e-mail: adrian.wozniak.1986@gmail.com (I am using this medium as a primary mode of communication). Try to ask the administrator of your log if possible. Also try to generate a current, and wife to ask though.